# sudo: source: command not found when executing tcl as sudo

Tags: linux, script, sudo

I have a test.tcl (has all permissions) which contains the following-

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh    
puts "hello, world"
```

This is how I'm executing my tcl script-

```
sudo source /opt/test.tcl
```

I got the output-

```
sudo: source: command not found
```

But I checked the availability of source and sudo using `whereis` command and they were available-

```
$ whereis sudo
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/share/man/man8/sudo.8.gz
$ whereis source
source: /usr/share/man/man1/source.1.gz
```

However, when I attempt to execute tcl as-

```
sudo tclsh /opt/test.tcl
```

I get the expected output-

```
hello, world
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` is a shell builtin. Your shell cannot find `source` for the same reason it can't find `cd` when you're using sudo - it is not a command. You can use the shell builtin `type` to check this yourself.

`source` executes the content of a file you specify *in your current shell*. That should be fine as long as you don't need an interactive shell, and that your current shell is tclsh. Read [here](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) for more information.

```
sudo tclsh /opt/test.tcl
```

will work, but it will run in a non-interactive shell.

If you do need to `source` the script for some reason, decide whether you need to do special permissions or not. If you must, you can `su` to root and `source` the script from there.

Also, the output you got for `$ whereis source`

```
source: /usr/share/man/man1/source.1.gz
```

seems to be a `man` page. So that probably wasn't going to be much use!